# is not a readable directory

Tags: android, react-native

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

> node_modules@react-native-firebase\messaging\android\build\intermediates\compiled_local_resources\release\out'
> is not a readable directory.

Answer (score 0):

delete `.gradle` folder from android folder and run `npx react-native run-android`